Hibernate SingleTableEntityPersister - Thousands of instances in heap
I'm running a docker Spring Boot 3.3 and Hibernate 6.5.2 on Amazon Corretto 21. After a few days of running, dumping the heap shows thousands of SingleTableEntityPersister instances, where i only have about 100 tables.
Any ideas why that leak is happening?
Running on Kubernetes, the JVM crashes with OOM

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
